# Making class private?

Tags: class, typescript, private

This question just popped up in my head but i want to make classes private somehow in typescript... So this is what is happening

In my folder Typescript/circle/circle.ts I have this:

```
class Circle {
  PI:number = 3.14;
  radius:number = 0;
  constructor(public radiusInput:number){
    this.radius = radiusInput  
  }
  getArea(){
    return this.PI*(this.radius*this.radius);
  }
  getCircumfrance(){
    return this.PI*2*this.radius;
  }
}
 var fourCircle:Circle = new Circle(5);
```

Now when i go to my other folder Typescript/enums/enums.ts, i can actualy create an instance of a Circle class. I dont want that.. I want to somehow make the Circle class private. How do you achieve that in typescript?

Comment: Did you wrap it in a [module](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules)?

Comment: No what is that? It dosent tell inside the website..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your class (and other types) in [modules](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules). This is the logical organization of your types in your files. Now you cant reference it from an external file unless you add the `export` keyword to the class definition. `module` is very similar to `namespace` in c#.

```
module MyTypes {
class Circle {
  PI:number = 3.14;
  radius:number = 0;
  constructor(public radiusInput:number){
    this.radius = radiusInput  
  }
  getArea(){
    return this.PI*(this.radius*this.radius);
  }
  getCircumfrance(){
    return this.PI*2*this.radius;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Oh igor thanks a bunch!! But i have just one tiny question. How do you like for example you decide you want that class in another place. How do you use it? Is it import? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you want to create an instance of that type you can add the `export` keyword so it becomes `export class Circle`. If the module name is different you have to either import that type at the top of your file OR use the fully qualified module name like `new MyTypes.Cicrle(12);`

Comment: Oh yeah just like Java. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: `module` keyword for "namespace" (was called "internal module" before TypeScript 1.5) should now be replaced with `namespace`. You can also try module loaders, so you can treat files as modules. :)